# find the rotation of one image with respect to other

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I have 2 images. One is the reference image and the other is the rotated version of the reference image. I would like to find what is the angle by which the 2nd image is rotated wrt 1st one.i want to do this automatically.

Comment: Step 1: Find or design an appropriate mathematical algorithm.  Step 2: Code the algorithm in Matlab.  If you need help with Step 1, I'd suggest asking math.stackexchange.com ; it's a fairly hard problem.  If you're on Step 2, what is your algorithm?

Comment: @aschepler: It's actually a problem that has been solved in the past few years.

Answer (score 4):

Brute-force it! Write a function to compare the intersection of the rotated images (sum of the difference or sum of the difference squared between each point), and then iterate through rotation angles to find the one corresponding to the minimum difference.

Although knowing matlab there's probably a function that just tells you the rotation, but it's called something weird.

Comment: Iterate over all possible `double` values between `-pi` and `pi`?  No.  But that helper function could be useful with a minimization solver....

Comment: Well yeah, depends how many significant figures you want. I figured it was worth keeping it as simple as it could be.

Comment: This would be doable if you knew the point in the image around which the rotation occurred.

Answer (score 4):

The general method for doing this is:

- Use an algorithm such as [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) to get a list of interest-point descriptors. These descriptors provide scale, direction and geometry of the interest points. The geometry information is scale- and rotation-invariant.
- Use a nearest-neighbor algorithm to match interest points in each of the pictures by comparing geometries.
- for each pair of matching interest points, compare their scale and rotation.

Ideally, all of the matching interest points will have the same relative scale and rotation.  However, variability in how the pictures were taken and inaccuracy in the previous stages will introduce variable scales and rotations, so:

- use an algorithm such as [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) to determine the best-fitting scale and rotation.

QED

Comment: @Joe: you can find SIFT here: http://www.vlfeat.org/ and RANSAC here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/1814-ransac-toolbox, both for Matlab, of course

Comment: There are versions for Windows, Mac, Linux and probably other Unices @Joe: as well.

Comment: nathan i just want to know any other method.like if i have four points from one image and corresponding four from other image,than in this case what to do to find the rotation between two except this Ransac approach.

Comment: @chee: Ransac is good when you have dozens of points. If you only have 4 points, and the only change is rotation, you can find the line connecting one pair of points in image A and the line connecting the corresponding points in image B, and comparing the slopes.  If you really want to be sure, repeat that for *all* the pairs you have and use the average

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** Since the question did not originally ask for an *automated* solution, I had posted this solution which requires a set of control points to be selected by the user for each image. Although the requirements in the question have been updated, I think this answer could still be useful for anyone wanting to do image registration in MATLAB, so I'm leaving it here...

**The non-automated approach:**

What you're asking about is known as [image registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration), and one option you have is to use the function [CP2TFORM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/cp2tform.html) from the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/).

In fact, there's a [very nice example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/cp2tform.html#f1-283712) in that function's documentation which looks like it tackles the same exact problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @chee I think that automatically is not a restriction you mentioned in the original question. Can you perhaps edit it to reflect all your requirements?

Comment: I'm not saying he should do it without a machine. I'm saying he did not mention he did not have hand clicked points. If he had hand clicked points @gnovice's answer is the simplest and will get the best results. It also would be a problem at the level of difficulty that a smart undergraduate can completely solve. If he doesn't have hand clicked points (wants a fully automatic solution), it is a research level questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1713-three-dimensional-reconstruction-from-planar-slices

This algorithm use *apriori* knowledge that the two objects are round. YMMV

Comment: The basis of that File Exchange post is to take two similar images and align them in the x and y and theta.  This is EXACTLY what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html) of how to recover a transformation between two images using local features and RANSAC from the Computer Vision System Toolbox.